# I have two files in different locations, one file contain .jpg and another file with .xml. I want to compare their names and print difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I compare the files in those two folders?

Image files:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
5.jpg
```

XML files:

```
1.xml
2.xml
3.xml
```

output:

```
5.jpg, 3.xml
```

Comment: Hi rak, you should give more details about your question. For example, what language do you use?

Comment: do you want to compare names or files?

Comment: @fatihyildizhan it's tagged python

Comment: Did our answers solve the problem(s)?  Please upvote whichever you used

Answer (score 1):

Compare without extension and find the different using `set`.

```
import os
f1 = os.listdir("foler1/")
f2 = os.listdir("folder2/")
f1 = set(map(lambda x:os.path.splitext(x)[0], f1))
f2 = set(map(lambda x:os.path.splitext(x)[0], f2))
r1 = list(map(lambda x:x+'.jpg', f1-f2))
r2 = list(map(lambda x:x+'.xml', f2-f1))
result = r1 + r2
print(result)
```

Comment: What's the run time?

Comment: O(n), but it loops a few times so not recommend for large folders.

Comment: Definitely shorter than the other.  Not sure about readability

Comment: could u please modify script to delete extra files( as mention above deleting 5.jpg and 3.xml)

Comment: Just use `os.remove("filename")`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is reasonably fast.  If you had huge directories, a hash table solution would be better.  Say you want to compare directory `XML/` and `images/`.

```
import os

def dir_diff(dir1, dir2):
  contents1 = sorted(   os.listdir(dir1))
  contents2 = sorted(   os.listdir(dir2))
  heads1=[]
  heads2=[]
  for fname in contents1:
    heads1.append(fname[:fname.rfind('.')] )
  for fname in contents2:
    heads2.append(fname[:fname.rfind('.')] )
  i=j=0
  out=[]
  print(heads2)
  print(heads1)
  while True:
    fname1=heads1[i]
    fname2=heads1[j]
    if   fname1 < fname2:
      out.append(contents1[i])
      i+=1
    elif fname2 < fname1:
      out.append(contents2[j])
      j+=1
    else:
      i+=1
      j+=1
    if i ==len(heads1) and j ==len(heads2):
      return out
    elif i==len(heads1):
      return out+contents2[j:]
    elif j==len(heads2):
      return out+contents1[i:]



if __name__=='__main__':
  folder1 = 'XML/'       # NOTE: change these to the folder names you want
  folder2 = 'images/'    # NOTE: change these to the folder names you want
  for fname in dir_diff(folder1, folder2):
    os.remove(fname)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rak/Desktop/NVS/rak.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(dir_diff('XML/', 'images/'))
  File "C:/Users/rak/Desktop/NVS/rak2.py", line 7, in dir_diff
    contents1 = sorted(   os.listdir(dir1))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'XML/'

Comment: Change the filenames in the line under `if __name__=='__main__':` to be whatever directories you need.  For instance, `for fname in dir_diff('folder1/', 'folder2/'): os.remove(fname)`